# We were all robbed of the "Beta" badge!

Tags: support, badges

There's a "Beta" badge for "Actively participated in the private beta"... but it looks like no one was awarded the badge when the public beta launched:  https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta

Is this a bug perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These have now been awarded to 58 diligent beta testers!

Comment: You are a fine person. Thank you.